# CORS missing in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cors

I have an application on the server, I am very sure that I have CORS enabled in this application since I have an AngularJs client (1.x) and it works perfectly.

but, now I'm migrating to Angular 4 and I get the following error.

> *Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ||my-url||. (Reason: CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)*

I have read many questions here and they all say that it is a problem in server-side but as I said my server works well and has CORS enabled, my problem is specifically in the client

**EDITED**

I have tried this in my service.ts

```
createAuthorizationHeader(): RequestOptions {
    // Just checking is this._options is null using lodash
    if (isNull(this._options)) {
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
      this._options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    }
    return this._options;
}

getStudies(): Observable<any> { 
    const options = this.createAuthorizationHeader();
    return this._httpService.get(this.WEB_API_URL, options)
    .map((response: Response) => console.log(response.json()))
}
```

**NEW EDIT**

it seems that it has not yet been clear **I have an angular application 1.x running on the same server as this new application in angular 4, THE BACKEND HAS CORS WELL CONFIGURED, IT IS BECAUSE THE OTHER APPLICATION ANGULAR 1 WORKS AND BEFORE WORKING I HAD TO CHANGE SOME PARAMETERS IN THE CLIENT**  I need to know how to do the same in angular 4

Comment: Well in that case it would be helpful if you can provide some running example

Comment: post your code structure

Comment: I have already edited the question

Comment: you don't set CORs headers on the client... you set them on the server... setting a CORs header on the client would kind of defeat the entire purpose of CORs

Comment: but the server has it enabled, I have another client in Angular 1.x and it works perfect

Comment: I'm gona guess your angular 1 client is coming from the same domain as your server and this new client is on a different domain, and your server side CORs was never configured correctly. You should post that code if you're having CORs issues, since cors headers set on a client are totally meaningless.

Comment: both clients are on the same server, and web-api on another server. in the angular 1.x client I had to enable cors to work

Comment: no, you needed to set withCredentials to true, which you also have to do in angular 2

Comment: It's pretty clear that your server does **not** have CORS **response** headers enabled. What host and port is your client running on? What host and port is `WEB_API_URL` pointing to? You should be able to inspect the request / response in your browser's *Network* console; what do the response headers look like?

Comment: THE BACKEND HAS CORS WELL CONFIGURED, IT IS BECAUSE THE OTHER APPLICATION ANGULAR 1 WORKS AND BEFORE WORKING I HAD TO CHANGE SOME PARAMETERS IN THE CLIENT

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue with React, and was able to solve it by adding the `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`. Just try if it works for you as well.

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` + `Your API URL`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Proxy to Backend](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) from [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

**Why?**

Adding those headers to your request doesn't help because these headers are supposed to be set by a server.

This is a security restriction built-in to your browser. When you make a http request to url which is on different domain than your application, browser first fires the `OPTIONS` request. In the response it checks these security headers. Only after they are sent it will send the original request (GET in your case).

You could either modify your server to send these headers or use cors proxy server.

**But really proper solution to this is to use built-in [Proxy to Backend](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) in `angular-cli`.**

You basically define the route which will be redirected to your API and then you make requests to relative url (like `/api`). Therefore no CORS restriction applies.

Comment: Won't this only help during development? Presumably, OP will want it to work in production as well

Comment: This will help only during development. In production you should either setup nginx with routing /api to your server or whitelist your domain on the server.

Comment: this works well, unfortunately I had to do this to continue developing, but there must be something better than this

Comment: open developer console in the chrome and see if there are CORS headers in the server response.

Answer (score -1):

add this to your request options:

```
this._options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers, withCredentials: true});
```

and you don't need to set all of those CORs headers, they aren't doing anything, those are request headers, cors headers need to be set in your response headers.

side note: I've run into an issue a few times with reusing request options in angular 2.  It seems you either need to set them at the http level or you need to recreate the headers every single time.  Try just returning a new RequestOptions object every time instead of attempting to reuse it, or use an http interceptor or extend your httpservice / request options to set the http requestoptions globally.

Comment: Given [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) primarily deals with cookies and OP has made no indication of such a requirement, what makes you think this is the answer?

Comment: More information here ~ https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-withcredentials