# How do I import react as a cdn?

Tags: reactjs, cdn

I just checked one of my sites which used to work fine and have noticed I'm now getting a CORS error on my React CDN. The site is https://timothytolley.com/ for reference of the errors. I have used the Scripts suggested on the React Docs.

As a bit of background, I'm using webpack for compiling and node and express for my server.

Error:

Access to script at 'https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js' (redirected from 'https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js') from origin 'https://timothytolley.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any suggestions would be awesome,

Cheers!

Comment: @Harvtronix Im not sure what you mean sorry, I'm only requesting from the Cdn

Comment: Sorry I think I misinterpreted the question

Comment: I found this. Looks like you're not alone perhaps? https://github.com/unpkg/unpkg.com/issues/174

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47252259/7427111

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue, I believe it's a problem with unpkg itself. When serving version 16.7 they are missing the `access-control-allow-origin` header. The older versions hosted on unpkg have this so this may be a derp with recently uploaded files.

In the meantime you can also try another cdn like cloudflare:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is reason of this problem, but I solved it when I changed 
`<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>` on

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If some of the URLs show `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and the rest do not, then it appears a problem with the caching layer or their CDN provider who might have changed the way their proxy works with CORS.

To quickly fix the issue, you can try a different [React CDN](https://pagecdn.com/lib/react):

```
<script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-3vo65ZXn5pfsCfGM5H55X+SmwJHBlyNHPwRmWAPgJnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-qVsF1ftL3vUq8RFOLwPnKimXOLo72xguDliIxeffHRc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In any case, please make sure that you always use `<script>` tag with `integrity` hash for maximum security.